# Ошибка с $(window).height

Tags: jquery, javascript

Почему у меня `$(window).height` абсолютно такое же по значению, что и `$(document).height`?

А когда пытаюсь вычислить `$(document).height - $(window).height`, то получается 0. В чем ошибка?

Вот этот код я скопировал с jsfiddle и он тоже не работает:

[код здесь](http://pastebin.com/Y3qDPeGu)

Comment: Пока не сформулируете вопрос, никто. Что вы хотите получить? Если `$(window).height` абсолютно такое же по значению, что и `$(document).height`, то тот факт, что `$(document).height - $(window).height`, не является сюрпризом.

Comment: @VladD я по моему все ясно сказал. Мне надо вычислить высоту документа без высоты окна браузера, а точнее что бы найти $(document).scrollTop, для проверки условия $(document).scrollTop == $(document).height - $(window).height

Comment: @igolka97: не могу воспроизвести: http://jsfiddle.net/MAE6A/
Может, ваш документ весь помещается в видимую область? Сможете привести пример на jsfiddle?

Comment: @igolka97, [вот простой пример того](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/MAE6A/1/), как может меняться значение, если мы возьмем пример, который показал выше VladD и всего лишь добавим в css правило:    * {        margin: 0;        padding: 0;    }

Comment: @VladD @istem @Deonis вот http://jsfiddle.net/igolka97/nYNu3/

Comment: работает на ура

Comment: @igolka97, Всё работает отлично. А вы бы кэш браузера почистили.

Comment: @igolka97: а браузер у вас какой?

Comment: @VladD да все и опера и хром и мозила и mobile safari

Comment: @igolka97: То есть вы хотите сказать, что у вас http://jsfiddle.net/igolka97/nYNu3/ **не выдаёт** alert, когда скролл достигает низа страницы?

Comment: @Deonis, все работает, я сейчас проверил, просто с телефона сидел)
почему то на JSfiddle все работает а на странице не хочет, я даже попробовал создать чистый пустой файл и и скопировать все с jsfiddle...
может проблема в jquery.js? у меня просто больше не остается предположений...

Comment: а зачем жквери для такой простецкой задачи?.. напишите то же чистым ЖС

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл :-)

Ваша проблема в том, что у вашего файла не указан DOCTYPE. Таким образом, браузер запускает режим совместимости с архаикой, и jQuery не может правильно вычислить размеры.

Comment: Всего вам лучшего и светлого, отличного pr и тИЦ'а, о посещаемости на ваших сайтах. аминь.
Вот только какой doctype указывать?

Comment: А я всегда думал: зачем этот доктайп...

Comment: Спасибо, пригодится, когда заведу себе сайт :) Насчёт доктайпа -- а какой у вас HTML? Наверное, [4.01 transitional](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) подойдёт. Проверьте всё же, не поломает ли это какую-то другую функциональность.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте с пом. [W3C Internationalization Checker](http://qa-dev.w3.org/i18n-checker/)
наличие BOM до doctype